# DNS - bind9 chroot jail - logging all queries

Tags: domain-name-system, logging, bind

I have my BIND9 running under a chroot jail, however, I'm having difficulties trying to log all queries.

I have bind under `/var/chroot/bind9/` where I created a `/var/chroot/bind9/var/log/` directory. I would like to have my query log under the normal /var/log/ directory, so I added the following to my `named.conf.local` and I did:

```
# touch /var/log/query.log
# ln -s /var/log/query.log /var/chroot/bind9/var/log/query.log
# chown -R bind:bind /var/chroot/bind9/var/log/

logging {
    channel query.log {
        file "/var/log/query.log";
        severity debug 3;
    };  
    category queries { query.log; };
};
```

But I keep getting: `named[2270]: isc_log_open '/var/log/query.log' failed: invalid file`
`
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

make sure `/var/chroot/bind9/var/log/` is owned by the user bind is run as.

seems you are on ubuntu.. follow this or disable apparmor

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bind9/+bug/236510

Comment: @Mike, yeah, actually /var/chroot/bind9/var/log/ is owned by bind:bind as well as `/var/chroot/bind9/var/log/query.log`

Comment: this is ubuntu?

Comment: @Mike: Debian 6 :)

Comment: it is probably the same.. check if apparmor is running

Comment: @Mike, actually I'm not running `apparmor`. However, the log for some reason ended up under: `/var/chroot/bind9/var/cache/bind/query.log`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use symlinks in the chroot jail that point outside of the jail - the symlinks get interpreted relative to the new root directory.

So your link:

```
# ln -s /var/log/query.log /var/chroot/bind9/var/log/query.log
```

when run `chroot('/var/chroot/bind9')` ends up pointing back to itself!